# clearInterval on condition is not working

Tags: javascript, date, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to print characters of a string in a timely manner. For that I used setInterval and used clearInterval to stop the setInerval after matching the string length. Code is as below,

```
const message = "Arnoldk";
const delay = 200;

let x = 0;
let tst = setInterval(_=>{
  const character = message.toLowerCase()[Math.floor(new Date / delay)%(message.length+1)]
  document.body.innerHTML = "<h2>" + message.substr(0, Math.floor(new Date / delay)%(message.length+1))
  if(++x == message.length){
    clearInterval(tst);
  }
},delay)
```

Sometimes it stops after printing the message ("Arnoldk"), but sometimes it goes another round and print "Ar" or "Arn". I don't understand how it goes on another round. Appreciate any help regarding this

Comment: Why are you using `Math.floor(new Date / delay)%(message.length+1)`? And why call it twice? setInterval doesn't run at exactly the interval specified, it just runs as soon as it can on or (almost always) after the interval is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Using `setTimeout` may give you [more control](https://develoger.com/settimeout-vs-setinterval-cff85142555b) over the loop. Try it like this

```js
const message = [..."Arnoldk"]; // spread to Array of characters
const delay = 200;
let h2 = document.querySelector("h2");
const timeIt = () => {
  h2.textContent += message.shift();
  message.length && setTimeout(timeIt, delay);
};
setTimeout(timeIt, delay);
```

```html
<h2></h2>
```

Comment: this is not printing letters in order. ex:- "rnldkar"

Comment: I did not touch your `char` initialisation (except for `message.length`). That seems to take a random character (dependent on the `delay` value). Why is that then?

Comment: Adjusted the answer: it now prints the characters in order.

Comment: @RobG Just for grouping and keep things within their own space. Removed it and replaced `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `Date` in calculations, sometimes the value will not be as expected. As we have `x` as incrementing value.

```js
const message = "Arnoldk";
const delay = 200;

let x = 0;
let tst = setInterval(_=>{
  
  document.body.innerHTML = "<h2>"+[...message].slice(0, x).join("");
  if(++x == message.length + 1){
    clearInterval(tst);    
  }
},delay)
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h2></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's giving me a coma between characters. "A,r,n,o,l,d,k"

Comment: Fixed commas :)